# Am having difficulties solving this problem, please help

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following system of linear equations:
Find values of $a, b, c$ such that the above system of linear equations has:

(i) exactly solution;
(ii) an infinite number of solution;
(iii) no solution;

$x + 5y + z = 0$

$x + 6y − z = 0$

$2x + ay + bz = c$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: We're not doing your homework.

Comment: What is difficult for you to understand , so we can help?

Comment: well i have placed the expression to an augmented matrices, then i  tried solving using the k constant method and from there its become confusing. so i tried making the  2x + ay + bz = c equal to zero, again i have a hard time solving it... am always used calculating K constant and finding the three solutions, but never with multiple Variables to find

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  Form an augmented matrix:   $\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&5&1&0\\1&6&-1&0\\2&a&b&c\end{array}\right)$.

Row reduce to find the conditions on $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: okay Chris Custer i did that thank you, so i ended up with this:

Comment: on my last row of the augmented matrices i have 0  (-10+a)  ( -2 +b)  c.

Comment: how to i find the value to a b and c from there ?

Comment: Ok.  Then $a=10, b=2$ and $c\neq0$ would be inconsistent.   On the other hand,  if  $a=10, b=2$ and $c=0$, it has at least a solution.   Now you need to back substitute.

Comment: Oh so (-10+a) ( -2 +b) c, each are equal to zero, enabling us to solve for a, b ,c , i was confused cause i was putting them as a one whole equation as (-10+a) ( -2 +b)  = c

Comment: I computed the determinant.   It's $b+2a-22$.  If the determinant isn't $0$ there's a unique solution.    If $a=10, b=2$ and $c=0$, there are infinitely many solutions.   Finally,  if $a=10, b=2$ and $c\neq0$, then there are no solutions.

Comment: okay i understand, but to be clear you've computed it using the Gauss Jordan elimination and you have ended up with b+ 2a−22, right?. so basically this problem is infinitely many solution but it still fulfills the the two other conditions

Comment: To compute the determinant I took the original matrix ($3×3$) and expanded by minors (also known as Laplace expansion,  I believe).

Comment: So we used both the determinant and row reduction (Gaußian elimination).

Comment: Sorry am still trying to sit on it so i can understand.. so i did the determinant with 3 x 3 matrices and got zero as a value and i took the 3 x 3 matrices and got the following                                                                                                                
x1 = - 11x3
x2 = 2x3
x3 - free , so is it from here you able to get the equation   b+ 2a−22 = 0 ?

Comment: The determinant (surely you've covered it), is just a number.   There's a method to compute it.   Do you have a book?  Anyway if you look up the method,  and then compute it, you'll get $b+2a-22$ (unless I erred, which is always possible).  Then we set it equal to zero.

Comment: yesssssssss i got it.. thank you.. it was my mistake calculating

Comment: Man thank you so much now its very clear ..i just need to do more tasks on this

Comment: Ok.   Best of luck.